# Error while reading XPath value

Tags: xml, xpath, error-handling, cdata

My response looks like below

```
<Response xmlns="http://example.com">
<PartnerCustomerNumber>24554691755043</PartnerCustomerNumber>
<ResultInfo>
  <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
  <ResultMessage>Success</ResultMessage>
</ResultInfo>
</Response>
```

I need to read the partner customer number using xpath. I used

```
/Response/PartnerCustomerNumber and //PartnerCustomerNumber
```

Both returned be error saying `Error parsing source entry[error:Unexpected element:CDATA]`

How can I bypass CDATA to go ahead and read the expected value.

This is working for my other calls. So I cannot modify much of my code, but modify my xpath.

Comment: Your xml has default namespace defined hence simply executing `/Response/PartnerCustomerNumber and //PartnerCustomerNumber` won't return you anything. You should take namespace into account while writing xpath or you should register the namespace using programming language you are using and then use the registered namespace variable in the xpath.

Comment: I don't see any CDATA section in your Xml document. Are you sure this happens when using the Xml document you showed?

Comment: Did it not give a line and column number where it occured?

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression is clearly wrong because it ignores the fact that the elements are in a namespace. But the error message about CDATA doesn't seem in any way related to that.